# Is it possible to make NGINX work with Liferay on Tomcat using http and https?

Tags: https, proxy, nginx, liferay, tomcat7

I'm trying to configure NGINX in front-end and Tomcat in back-end in order to make it work together.

I configured my Tomcat server.xml with 2 connectors :

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" proxyPort="443" proxyName="www.myhost.com" connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />


<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" proxyPort="80" proxyName="www.myhost.com" connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

My NGINX server receives requests when users call my website on **http**://www.myhost.com and on **https**://www.myhost.com.
On each call (excluding cache...), NGINX sends a request to my Tomcat server on 8080 port or on 8443 depending on the scheme of original request (http or https).

It works fine but Tomcat seems to give wrong information to my webapp (actually, my webapp is Liferay). It gives a wrong server host.

For example, when I call my server on **http**://www.myhost.com, NGINX calls Tomcat on **8080** port but Liferay seems to receive a request with a bad server host (http**s**://www.myhost.com/).
Liferay uses this server host to build links.
Actually, all the links Liferay is building match this pattern : http**s**://www.myhost.com/....

According to me, with my configuration, it should work like this :

- Tomcat receives a request on 8080 port.
- Tomcat understand the fact that my call was on **http**://www.myhost.com
- Tomcat should give to Liferay webapp the proxyHost (www.myhost.com) and the proxyPort (80) as Tomcat received the message on port (8080) (Liferay should retrieve those information using request.getServerPort() and request.getServerHost() [Tomcat configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html))
- Liferay should consider those information to build links URL (menu...).

Here is my problem. Liferay gets the wrong configuration : the one on https scheme.

I used this post to configure NGINX [Install nginx on ubuntu 12.04 and connect it to Tomcat](http://liferay-implementation.blogspot.fr/2012/07/install-nginx-on-ubuntu-1204-and.html).
This post doesn't explain how to do this for https.
In my context, I wrote it twice for http and https.

Did anyone already resolve this problem ?

Comment: Please post your nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the recommended way to do this. If you have a proxy like NGINX (in my case pound) then the SSL layer should be left up to the proxy. This allows the proxy to examine the HTTP headers to provide 'sticky' sessions where a user stays on a single tomcat web server out of the cluster.

In my case I get tomcat to listen on localhost:8080
Pound listens on external ip:80 and only returns a redirect to https (external ip:443)
Pound also listens on external ip:443, decrypts the SSL and proxies to tomcat on 8080 (actually a cluster of tomcats)

You also need to set some params in portal-ext.properties:
web.server.http.port=80
web.server.https.port=443
web.server.protocol=https

This tells LifeRay to generate all links as HTTPS on port 443 which matches the public interface of the SSL proxy.

Now the problem is that if you connect directly to tomcat on 8080 LifeRay will generate 'wrong' links and send you off to the proxy. I still haven't found a way to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Using nginx as a reverse proxy for your tomcat installation is possible with these lines of code in your nginx site configuration.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.server.com;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Host    $http_host;
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
```

This allows you to set up another virtual host (server_name) on nginx, forwarding to your tomcat installation at http://127.0.0.1:8080. Add SSL/TLS support here, not in tomcat configuration.

I have not checked webdav, but using the portal with a webbrowser works like a charm.